# Embedded 3 tables in Entity Framework Core and Cosmos DB

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem with embedding 3 tables in Entity Framework Core and Cosmos DB.

For example, the first table `[Appointment Register]` will have one-to-many relation with `[Appointment Detail]` (one customer can make an appointment for many customers) and one `[Appointment Detail]` will have a one-to-many relation with `[Item Service]` (because one customer will do one/ many services at the same time).

Something like these classes here show:

```
public class AppointmentRegister
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int? NumberofCustomer { get; set; } = 1;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public List<AppointmentRegisterDetail> appointmentRegisterDetails { get; set; } = new List<AppointmentRegisterDetail>();
}

public class AppointmentRegisterDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string? AppointmentRegister { get; set; }
    public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public List<NailsServices> NailsServices { get; set; } = new List<NailsServices>();
}

public class NailsServices
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

How can I config it with Entity Framework Core and Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in one nested document or separately in the same partition but you will need to link them together using an id from a parent to a child document, e.g:

```
public class AppointmentRegisterDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid AppoinmentRegisterID { get; set; }
    ...the rest fields
}

public class NailsServices
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string AppointmentRegisterDetailId { get; set; }
    ...the rest fields
}
```

It depends on how your application will work with the data, whether you are planning to retrieve them always together or separately. You can also take a look at the model and partition data tutorials. Maybe it will help you with making the decision and better understanding data modeling in NoSQL databases:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-model-partition-example
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utdxvAhIlcY